# 20.04 LTS Changing OSK ( OnScreen Keyboard ) colours

Tags: onscreen-keyboard

Is there a way to change the background and text colours used to display the OSK?

I would like to have bold Cyan text on a Black background.

Comment: It is possible.. but it needs to create a new shell theme.. what is the shell theme you are using rite now?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible by editing the css file for gnome-shell theme being used..

need to edit the portion `/* On-screen Keyboard */` from the css file..
for example I have edited some portion to make cyan background and bold black text..

Configuration 1

```
.keyboard-key {
  color: cyan;
  background-color: black;
  border-color: #cdc7c2;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  icon-shadow: 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  font-size: 16pt;
  font-weight: bold;
  min-height: 1.2em;
  min-width: 1.2em;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 8px; }
```

[image]

Configuration 2

```
.keyboard-key {
  color: #2e3436;
  background-color: cyan;
  border-color: #cdc7c2;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  icon-shadow: 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  font-size: 16pt;
  font-weight: bold;
  min-height: 1.2em;
  min-width: 1.2em;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 8px; }
```

[image]

Similar way you can achieve other keys background color also under the section `/* On-screen Keyboard */`